# Query not executing, unable to run in Big

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Quer logs.type = apps.log_type
WHERE logs.datetime  query 
Quer logs.type = apps.log_type
WHERE logs.datetime
```

query `enter code here` : the sql

Query not executing, unable to run in sql server

Comment: Well `Quer` is not valid SQL. Why do you think that should work in SQL Server (or any standard compliant SQL database)?

Comment: looks like this question was just intentionally broken! and btw, was originally clearly for BigQuery. sad to see such practice

Answer (score 1):

For GROUP BY to work it should be used along with aggregate functions in the SELECT list

Something like below example:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  MAX(logs.datetime) latest_datetime, 
  logs.type, 
  SUM(LENGTH(logs.message)) messages_length, 
  apps.name 
FROM logs INNER JOIN apps 
ON logs.type = apps.log_type
WHERE logs.datetime > "2017-07-01T00:00:00" 
AND logs.datetime < "2017-07-02T00:00:00"
GROUP BY apps.name, logs.type
```

so the rule of thumb is - any field in `SELECT` statement should be either in `GROUP BY` list or (if not in GROUP BY) to be used with Aggregate Function